# PHP Source code that help user sharing their favorites song/novel/comics

Tags: list, sharing, favorites

I'm looking for a source code that help me making list of songs/novels/comics and user can add it to their favorites so that others can see it.
It's may have the function like dicussion board too...

But i can't find any. Anyone can tell me that there are source code that can make it?

It'd be great if there are...

I can not coding so i'm looking for a ready to use...

Thank for your reading time.

Vuong Quoc.

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a place for asking for codes like this

Comment: Oops! Sorry! I search alot and thought might find out something here!